# How to seperate asset pipeline with different layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a new project, and I have created 2 layouts for it.

The 1st layout is the main layout used for the application.

The 2nd layout is for the 'beta' landing page, where users can signup via email to recieve updates on the website.  I am using bootstrap for this section.

My assets folder looks like:

```
/assets/
/assets/bootstrap/
/assets/.... (default folders generated by rails 4)
```

**Is it possible for asset pipeline to server the assets for the 'beta' layout from the /assets/bootstrap tree?**

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use two layout files in `app/views/layouts`: one you just leave like it is and then you create a second that will be called something like `application_bootstrap.html.erb`. In the second one you will include a stylesheet link tag like `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap" %>`. In the `assets` directory you will have the regular `application.css` where you have to make sure not to include the `assets/bootstrap` directory and a new `bootstrap.css` which simply requires the `assets/bootstrap/` tree to be included.

Then in you controllers you can switch the layouts: `layout application_bootstrap` and it will include the new layout file which in return includes the new CSS that you created. Of course you could also switch the layout in the `application_controller.rb` based on user settings or whatever you choose.